Assert in TypeScript type definition
Suppose I have a type definition like the following:
type FollowPath<T, P> =
    // If the first element of P is a key of T, advance
    P extends [infer E extends keyof T, ...infer Ps] ?
        FollowPath<T[E], Ps>
    // else if its an empty array, return T, else the paths array is invalid and we return never
    : P extends [] ? T : never;

If P's first element is not a key of T and P is not empty then the object property path is invalid. I would like to throw an error in that case. Is it possible?
I currently return never, but it is a bit implicit and does not prevent one from "calling" the type definition with invalid type arguments.

throw an error implies you want to throw a runtime exception. Assuming you want to produce a type error instead you can always do something like this if never isn't suitable.

Throwing custom error messages from type checking is not supported: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23689

Does this answer your question? How to throw custom Typescript compile message when checking for generic's key?

What you have done is correct. If you return never, you will cause an application error later: never cannot be assigned to type x

@RemoH.Jansen You probably want it the other way around. 'X' is not assignable to type never ;)

You can use a generic constraint like this to restrict the tuple type for P — although I fail to see the usefulness of the type in the question other than to validate the concrete type for P. Is that the purpose of the type? If this information meets your needs, I can write an answer. If not — what did I miss?

I know I can create a specific type that checks if the supplied tuple is actually the path - the question was more about a custom compile message, which @Bergi seems to be referring to. Seems it is impossible to do in an idiomatic way
